# How to solve error inserting image while using Glide?

Tags: android, image, android-contentresolver, mediastore, android-glide

I'm trying to load a picture using Glide and then creating an intent with it to crop it.

It is working on API 21+ devices, but not below.

This is the code:

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(wallurl)
    .asBitmap()
    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(final Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
            if (resource != null) {
                if (dialogApply != null) {
                    dialogApply.dismiss();
                }
                dialogApply = new MaterialDialog.Builder(context)
                        .content(R.string.downloading_wallpaper)
                        .progress(true, 0)
                        .cancelable(false)
                        .show();

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            Uri wallUri = getImageUri(context, resource);
                            if (wallUri != null) {
                                dialogApply.dismiss();
                                Intent setWall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
                                setWall.setDataAndType(wallUri, "image/*");
                                setWall.putExtra("png", "image/*");
                                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(setWall, getString(R.string.set_as)), 1);
                            } else {
                                dialogApply.setContent(R.string.error);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        }
    });

public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }
```

And this is the error I get:

```
E/MediaStore﹕ Failed to insert image
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:146)
            at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:611)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:922)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:669)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:645)
            at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:902)
            at jahirfiquitiva.iconshowcase.activities.ViewerActivity.getImageUri(ViewerActivity.java:366)
            at jahirfiquitiva.iconshowcase.activities.ViewerActivity$5$2$1.run(ViewerActivity.java:335)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

May someone help me to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to prefetch the image like this

```
            FutureTarget<File> future = Glide.with(applicationContext)
                    .load(yourUrl) 
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {

                        //do your stuff

                        return false;
                }
            })
            .into(500, 500);
```

and on the other activity you just load the image normally because it will be cached

Comment: It says RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() cannot be applied to RequestListener<String, Bitmap>() ... what should I do?

Comment: I just edited my answer. You need to user RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable> instead of RequestListener<String Bitmap>

Comment: It gives me a GlideDrawable, and I need a Bitmap... Or how would I get the GlideDrawable uri, then?

Comment: Oh, and when using GlideDrawable, downloadOnly cannot be resolved

Comment: No need for you to send the bitmap to the other screen, when you use glide on first screen you will cache the image so, on the second screen it will load without need to load it again. the downloadOnly need to me changed to .into();. i will change the the example

Comment: It seems that you don't understand what I try to do. I need a bitmap, in its full resolution, to be able to get its uri, and then start an intent to crop that bitmap. The cropper isn't in my app, but default apps in device.